# VBA: Seeking help in code modification

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA learner, and I am trying to build a VBA project for improving my knowledge. There is a slight confusion on how to populate different data(based on some condition) to a set of same field.

I have 3 scenarios:

Scenario 1: User select all the checkbox
Scenario 2: User select only 1 or 2 checkbox
Scenario 3: User not selecting anything

My code will work perfectly with scenarios 1 and 3 but not able to figure it out how to accomplish scenario 2.

My expectation is to populate the values from Cell B3 to B17 based on what user selects when Userform pop up to him. If he selects only 1 field corresponding values should be populated from B3 – B8, if he selects 2 checkboxes then the 1st corresponding value will be populated from B3 – B8 and 2nd set from B9 – B14 and so on.  Please find the images below for better understanding

**Userform**
[image]

**Example of Scenario 1**
[image]

**Example of Scenario 3**
[image]

**VBA Code**

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 3
Do While i < 8 And UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox6.Value = True
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "India"
    i = i + 1
Loop

Do While i < 13 And UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox7.Value = True
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "Germany"
    i = i + 1
Loop

Do While i < 18 And UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox7.Value = True
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "Hongkong"
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want something more like the code below. This code could be further improved to be a function, into which you pass the name of the country and the current row, thus eliminating the duplicated code

```
 Sub PopulateSheet()
 Dim lngCurrentRow As Long

'start row
lngCurrentRow = 3

If chkIndia Then

    Sheet.Range("B" & lngCurrentRow & ":B" & lngCurrentRow + 4) = "India"

    lngCurrentRow = lngCurrentRow + 5

End If

 If chkGermany Then

    Sheet.Range("B" & lngCurrentRow & ":B" & lngCurrentRow + 4) = "Germany"

    lngCurrentRow = lngCurrentRow + 5

End If


If chkHK Then

    Sheet.Range("B" & lngCurrentRow & ":B" & lngCurrentRow + 4) = "Hong Kong"

    lngCurrentRow = lngCurrentRow + 5

End If

End Sub
```

UPDATED WITH FUNCTION:

```
Sub PopulateSheet()
Dim lngCurrentRow As Long

'start row
lngCurrentRow = 3

If chkIndia Then Call WriteOutput("India", lngCurrentRow)
If chkGermany Then Call WriteOutput("Germany", lngCurrentRow)
If chkHK Then Call WriteOutput("Hong Kong", lngCurrentRow)

End Sub

Function WriteOutput(strCountry As String, ByRef lngRowToWriteTo As Long)

ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lngRowToWriteTo & ":B" & lngRowToWriteTo + 4) = strCountry

lngRowToWriteTo = lngRowToWriteTo + 5

End Function
```

You can then set the 4 to be a constant (number of times you want the country to appear in the sheet) and the 5 to be constant + 1

UPDATED WITH CONSTANTS, this gives maximum flexibility:

```
    Private Const START_ROW As Long = 3
    Private Const NUM_COUNTRY_ROWS As Long = 4
    Private Const COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO As String = "B"

    Sub PopulateSheet()
    Dim lngCurrentRow As Long

        'start row
        lngCurrentRow = START_ROW

        If True Then Call WriteOutput("India", lngCurrentRow)
        If True Then Call WriteOutput("Germany", lngCurrentRow)
        If True Then Call WriteOutput("Hong Kong", lngCurrentRow)

    End Sub

    Function WriteOutput(strCountry As String, ByRef lngRowToWriteTo As Long)

        ActiveSheet.Range(COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO & lngRowToWriteTo & ":" & COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO & lngRowToWriteTo + NUM_COUNTRY_ROWS) = strCountry

        lngRowToWriteTo = lngRowToWriteTo + NUM_COUNTRY_ROWS + 1

    End Function
```

UPDATED TO INCLUDE MERGE (note you now only need to write the country in once)

```
Private Const START_ROW As Long = 3
Private Const NUM_COUNTRY_ROWS As Long = 4
Private Const COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO As String = "B"

Sub PopulateSheet()
Dim lngCurrentRow As Long

    'start row
    lngCurrentRow = START_ROW

    If chkIndia Then Call WriteOutput("India", lngCurrentRow)
    If chkGermany Then Call WriteOutput("Germany", lngCurrentRow)
    If chkHK Then Call WriteOutput("Hong Kong", lngCurrentRow)

End Sub

Function WriteOutput(strCountry As String, ByRef lngRowToWriteTo As Long)

    With ActiveSheet

        .Range(COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO & lngRowToWriteTo) = strCountry

        .Range(.Range(COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO & lngRowToWriteTo), .Range(COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO & lngRowToWriteTo + NUM_COUNTRY_ROWS)).Cells.Merge

    End With

    lngRowToWriteTo = lngRowToWriteTo + NUM_COUNTRY_ROWS + 1

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Jpad Limited the modified one worked perfectly, will you guide me how the FUNCTION part is exactly working here ?

Comment: Sure. You are taking the start row you want to put data in (should also be a constant) in this case 3. You are then running the function, and telling it what row to start on, and to put 4 country names in from that row. Then you increase the row start number by 5, then check the next checkbox. You are basically just storing the last row you wrote to, for next time

Comment: Thank you @ Jpad Limited . how to accomodate merge into this fields after performing this code ?  do we have to set the rage ? while performing each loop ? And or if i want to skip 1 or 2 Fields/rows before filling next values ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Do` use an `If` statement

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 3
If UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox6.Value = True Then
  Do While i < 8
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "India"
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End If

If UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox7.Value = True Then
  Do While i < 13
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "Germany"
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End If 

If UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox7.Value = True Then
  Do While i < 18
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "Hongkong"
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End If
```

Comment: Thank you @David G.

Answer (score 2):

this is another method.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngT As Range
    Dim rngDB() As Range, n As Integer, i As Integer

    If UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox6.Value Then
        Set rngT = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(5) = "India"
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve rngDB(1 To n)
        Set rngDB(n) = rngT.Resize(5)
    End If
    If UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox7.Value Then
        Set rngT = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(5) = "Germany"
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve rngDB(1 To n)
        Set rngDB(n) = rngT.Resize(5)
    End If
    If UF1_Location_and_Role.CheckBox8.Value Then
        Set rngT = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        rngT.Resize(5) = "Hongkong"
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve rngDB(1 To n)
        Set rngDB(n) = rngT.Resize(5)
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To n
        rngDB(i).Merge
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ...as long as there is no data in Column B underneath the data you are trying to put in..

Comment: Thank you @Dy.Lee. what should i do, if i want to merge those fields after performing this code ?